# POST x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json at the same time with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to POST a request with x-www-form-urlencoded data (username, password) and application/json data (settings for a query) at the same time with Python requests.

Is this even possible? I use Postman to do this at the moment and it works.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Either u can use multipart contentype or add jsondata field on x-www-form-urlencoded data while u passing username ,password